# MySQL - Join as zero if record Not IN

Tags: mysql, join

To explain by example, take two tables, A and B

```
Table A
id  foo
 1   x
 2   y
 3   z


Table B
id  aid bar
 1   3   50
 2   1  100
```

An example join

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM a, b WHERE a.id = b.aid;
```

Garners a result of

```
foo  bar
 z    50
 x   100
```

What I would like to do is get all values of `foo` and for any instances where there isn't a corresponding `bar` value, return 0 for that column.

```
foo  bar
 z    50
 y     0
 x   100
```

My best guess was something along the lines of

```
SELECT foo, bar AS br FROM a, b 
WHERE a.id = b.aid 
OR a.id NOT IN (SELECT aid FROM b);
```

But that returns duplicates and non-zero values for bar.

Possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT a.foo, COALESCE(b.bar, 0) as bar
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.aid
```

Comment: Excellent.  I was really over-thinking this.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.foo, IFNULL(b.bar, 0) AS bar
FROM tablea AS a
LEFT JOIN tableb AS b
  ON a.id=b.aid
```